# Что лучше: делегат или список объектов?

Tags: c#

Что в плане производительности лучше: использовать делегат, или хранить список объектов и при необходимости перебирать его и вызывать у каждого объекта нужный метод?

Comment: Каким образом Вы собираетесь перебирать список объектов разных типов и вызывать у них нужный метод? Рефлексией? Тогда ни о какой производительности такого подхода и речи не идёт. Или Вы хотите реализовать шаблон обсервера в стиле Java, и хранить в списке объекты обертки, которые вызывают нужный метод у нужного объекта? В любом случае это всё ненужные костыли. Советую не заморачиваться и пользоваться инструментами, которые даёт Вам язык программирования - делегатами/событиями.

Comment: @anu Ок, спасибо

Comment: Ну если все объекты реализуют некий интерфейс, в котором этот метод объявлен, то почему нет? Никакая рефлексия не нужна. Сильно зависит от задачи. Потому что список делегатов может быть семантически хуже — не выражать намерений кода.

Comment: @Андрей То есть, если напрямую вызвать метод у объекта, который реализует интерфейс, получится быстрее, чем вызывать делегат?

Comment: А зачем вам быстрее? У вас именно там бутылочное горлышко? Я думаю, что затраты на вызов в обоих случаях будет примерно равны и это вообще не место для оптимизации. Тут более важно, какой код будет лучше читаться, поддерживаться и лучше отображать задумку автора.

Comment: @Андрей Понял вас, спасибо